# Easeljs getBounds, when are dimensions set?

Tags: createjs, easeljs

I'm importing someone's createjs application into an application loader which imports each developers application javascript to a global canvas. The application is working standalone but when I load the javascript dynamically I'm getting some strange behavior surrounding the `getBounds()` function.

I have some text created like this:

```
dialogText = new createjs.Text(text, 'bold ' + (28 * scale) + 'px Calibri', '#FFFFFF');
```

Then later on I use `dialogText.getBounds()` which returns `null`.

I try console logging dialogText and I can see that it is set and there is a value `_bounds` which reads `null`.

At what point do these values get set when the element in drawn to the canvas?

*Note: I'm already adding the text to a `createjs.Container()` which has its bounds set before I run `getBounds()`.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_bounds` property reflects a value that is manually set on the DisplayObject - which is helpful if you know the bounds of something that can't calculate it (like a Shape). It will always be `null`, unless you set it directly.

I tested your code, and it seems fine. Are you sure the `scale` or `text` values are not null? Maybe hard-code them to see if it works.

Do you have a sample somewhere? I noticed in [the GitHub issue you posted](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues/843) that you mentioned it worked fine without RequireJS (though you don't mention that here). I would definitely ensure that the values are being set properly.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/25dwoxta/), as well as a [simpler one with no EaselJS stage](http://jsfiddle.net/25dwoxta/1). Note that I have Calibri installed on my machine, so you might get different results if you are loading it in.

**Sample code:**

```
var dialogText = new createjs.Text("This is some text", 'bold ' + (28 * 1.5) + 'px Calibrix', '#FFFFFF');
console.log(">>",dialogText.getBounds());
```

Comment: Thanks @Lanny I posted two links in my question just to show you how the one works but not the other. I need to look more into the issue to figure out exactly what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

For a quick reference, I pasted EaselJS's update regarding **getBounds()**:

[image]

(*This dates back from "August 21, 2013", not sure if this is still necessary nowadays, but using **setBounds(x, y, w, h)** helped me with Shapes today [in 2017] actually!*)

Source: http://blog.createjs.com/update-width-height-in-easeljs/

Comment: That being said - I'm not sure if using **setBounds(...)** would actually override the internally calculated bounds from EaselJS's Text objects.

Comment: Yes, it will override automatically calculated values.